# Renaming files using PowerShell gives "Access to path is denied"

Tags: powershell

Again, like any other "Square Bracket" related PowerShell here, I've read many others similar problems. But the thing is, the error codes I get aren't even similar to any of them ("Access Denied"). Which might be why most of those solutions are ineffective.

Basically I want to batch rename files in a folder based on inputs. The problem *only* arise when you put and execute the .ps1 file on a dir with square brackets (`[]`). Removing those brackets shows smooth operation.

The important bits of my program:

```
$Replace = Read-Host -Prompt 'To Replace'
$New = Read-Host -Prompt 'With'

Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.Name $_.Name.Replace("$Replace", "$New") }
```

Meanwhile, I get a bunch of error codes which are similar to one another like this:

```
Move-Item : Access to the path is denied.
At D:\[Folder]\BatchReplaceWords.ps1:33 char:36
+ ... ch-Object { Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.Name $_.Name.Replace("$Replace" ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\Syst...y.format.ps1xml:FileInfo) [Move-Item], Unauthorized AccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

More info: Windows 10 with PowerShell version 5.

Comment: Use the `-WhatIf` switch to see what is supposed to happen: `move-item -WhatIf -LiteralPath ...` . This is an easy way to see if the file name(s) are going to make sense.

Comment: `-LiteralPath $_.PSPath`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Same error. Though I'd add that I'm trying to avoid giving a full path into ".Replace" since it might replace something inside the path itself (well, at least to my knowledge).

Comment: @vonPryz Wow, somehow the the program tries to move a target on a System32 folders.

One of them among many messages with System32 directory:
`What if: Performing the operation "Move Directory" on target "Item: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en Destination: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en\en".`

And none of them even targeting the current folder (the one with square brackets ( `[ ]` ).

Comment: @SecretMessenger That's why I suggested using `PSPath` (or `FullName`) for the first argument

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, I have and exactly the same response.

Comment: How are you calling your script?  You're calling `Get-ChildItem` without args.

Comment: You don't actually specify a path argument to `Get-ChildItem` - which folder are you expecting the files to come from?

Comment: Confirmed that the whole process takes place in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ ` instead of its actual dir `D:\[Test]`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The folder where the .ps1 file placed in. It works flawlessly in a dir without any square bracket.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Emmm just running it? Doesn't Get-ChildItem run just fine without any args though?

Comment: @SecretMessenger GCI grabs whatever directory you're executing the script from, which can also depend on profile, or user context.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yeah, which is what I want. Is it very problematic though?

Comment: It's problematic you didn't know how you were calling GCI in the first place

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Well yeah I don't really understand the whole PowerShell stuff, since I do it only for casually automating processes. I only know that GCI gets a list of items on a dir based on its args. Without any, it should get all items on current dir; which is what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a location to `Get-ChildItem`'s `-LiteralPath` parameter if you want to enumerate files in a folder with square brackets.

The location of the script can be found through `$PSScriptRoot` (PowerShell 3.0+) or through the `$MyInvocation` automatic variable:

```
if(-not(Get-Variable PSScriptRoot -Scope Script)){
    $PSScriptRoot = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
}

$Replace = Read-Host -Prompt 'To Replace'
$New = Read-Host -Prompt 'With'

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace($Replace,$New)}
```

Comment: Yep, this solves it. Though I still wonder why square brackets suddenly break things up. The last line of code I used should've been the solution to a lot of square brackets-related questions I found after browsing a lot. Yet here I am.

Answer (score 0):

```
$TextToReplace = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the filename text to replace:'
$ReplacementText = Read-Host -Prompt 'What are you replacing this text with?'
$Path = Read-Host -Prompt 'Which path do these files exist?'

GCI -Path $Path |
  ? { $_.FullName -like "*$TextToReplace*" } |
  % { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $ReplacementText }
```

Comment: Hmmm, not my ideal solution since it asks for path input. Though can be modified with some lines of code. Result: It doesn't do anything in a dir with square bracket. Meanwhile throwing `Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` error on a normal dir.